# Is there a Python equivalent to SQL's "WHERE LIKE "%%"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to add a new column into a Pandas DataFrame. I want it to be based on my 'SKU' column and basically say "if the SKU ends with -RF, write "USED" into the new column, elif SKU ends with -NEW, write "NEW" into the new column, else don't do anything.

I know in my SQL you can write this like "...WHERE LIKE "%-RF", I'm looking for something that does the same job as that.

This was the (unfinished) function as I was attempting to make it. I'm trying to figure out what goes in place of the "something_to_do_with" placeholders.

```
    if sku_column == something_to_do_with_-RF:
        val = "USED"
    elif sku_column == something_to_do_with_-NEW:
        val = "NEW"
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Use the `.endswith()` method.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! Could you tell me how to apply this to look through a specific column from the original DataFrame? Would it be " df('sku').endswith(-RF) "? The column I'm attempting to search being called 'sku'.

Comment: Someone posted an answer 10 minutes ago. Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop.

```
df.loc[df['sku'].str.endswith("-RF"),'column'] = 'USED'
df.loc[df['sku'].str.endswith("-NEW"),'column'] = 'NEW'
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of SQL's joker `%a_text` in pandas is [**`pandas.Series.str.endswith`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html)(a_text).

In your case, it might be better to use [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex to capture the desired text and map it with a pre-defined dictionnary.

Try this :

```
dico = {'RF': 'USED', 'NEW': 'NEW'}

df['new_col'] = df['SKU'].str.extract('.-(RF|NEW)$', expand=False).map(dico)
```